# CakePHP checkbox for values 0 and 1

Tags: cakephp, checkbox

I want to generate a CakePHP checkbox for a boolean field of my database, but it is resisting. I have tried in many different ways, but it's not working.
The checkbox is always 1, no matter if selected or not.
Any idea what might be the problem?

```
echo $this->FormTB->input(
    'puntuacion', 
    array(
        'checked' => true, 
        'value' => 1, 
        'label' => 'Puntuar esta empresa',
        'class' => 'checkbox', 
        'data-id' => 'puntuar'
    )
);
```

I have tried removing the `"value" => 1` part, nothing changed.

Comment: Of course its always 1. That is the "checked" value. If you do not want to send the checked value do not check the checkbox. Just by not checking it you do not explicitly send 0. You send NOT the value which is totally the same in the end and is automatically represented as 0 in the controller/model after the POST.

Comment: What I want is to send value 1 if it's checked, and send 0 if it's not checked.
@Juhana, it's the name I've given to bootstrap's form helper

Comment: Thats already done internally, as pointed out by me twice already.

Comment: please look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947986/cake-php-checkboxes/19638821#19638821

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out multiple times in the comment, that is exactly how cakephp operates internally: a "not checked" is internally transferred to a boolean FALSE - which again is equivalent to integer 0 - in the controller/model.

So this suffices:

```
echo $this->FormTB->input(
    'puntuacion', array(
    'label' => 'Puntuar esta empresa',
    'class' => 'checkbox',
    'data-id' => 'puntuar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `'checked' => true, 'value' => 1,` part